# Any twitter boostrap(ish) theme for Drupal 6?

Tags: theming

I'd like to make a legacy D6 site's theme more responsive. I love to be able to use the omni-present twitter bootstrap theme or something that comes close to it in responsiveness. I know that there is a [quite a few](https://drupal.org/project/themes/bootstrap?f%5B0%5D=bs_project_sandbox:0&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc) for drupal 7+  but could not fine any for D6 on Drupal site.

So I'm wondering if there is any mature D6 Bootstrap theme? And if not, how hard is it to convert a D7 theme to D6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you may start creating your own theme (you can use any light weight theme as base theme) from scratch using Twitter Bootstrap, or you may check the couple of options present on the sandbox project, which contains experimental code for developer use, as below:

- HTML5 CSS3 base Drupal 6 theme built using Twitter Bootstrap: https://drupal.org/sandbox/drewkennelly/1276010 (Also check issue queue of it: https://drupal.org/node/1276060)
- A Drupal 6 Theme with Bootstrap installed: https://github.com/sdmunoz/Drupal-6-Theme-Bootstrap
- Twitter bootstrap theme for Drupal 6 created using zen as base theme: http://www.eliotdill.com/2012/06/twitter-bootstrap-theme-for-drupal-6/

If any of the above suits your requirement, then you can use them and modify it as per your need, instead of creating it from the scratch.

Comment: Have you tried any of them? How mature are they?

Comment: @alfish No I havn't tried them, but you can check if they suits your purpose (download them and test it on the local)